# Is solution of Laplace's equation square integrable

Tags: potential-theory

I am wondering if the solution of Laplace's equation (e.g. electrostatic potential $\Phi$ which satisfies $\nabla^2\Phi=0$) is square-integrable? I am confused, because in one dimension in the large distance limit, $\Phi(x)\sim\frac{1}{x}$. So $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\Phi^2\ dx<\infty$. However, if I go to the large distance limit in the three dimensions, $\int_{r=0}^{\infty}\int_ {\theta=0}^{\pi}\int_{\phi=0}^{2\pi}\Phi(r)^2\ d^3{\bf r}$. This seems to diverge, even though $\Phi\sim\frac{1}{r}$. It is true that the higher order multipole terms converge, but the monopole term still seems to dominate.

For me it looks odd that such a basic principle should exhibit different behaviour in one and three dimensions. Can anyone kindly explain if I am going wrong?

Regards,
Kolahal

Comment: Harmonic functions are far from unique; there are many of them and many of them aren’t square-integrable. An easy example is a nonzero constant, and a nontrivial example is a linear function.

Comment: Hello Qiaochu, thank you for the clarification. So, there is not a general rule, I suppose.

Comment: Ah, in fact I’m being silly: the only harmonic function on $\mathbb{R}^n$ which is square-integrable is the zero function. The example you give is a harmonic function on $\mathbb{R}^n$ minus the origin though.

Comment: What in two dimensions? Isn't it square-integrable? as $\Phi\sim\frac{1}{r}$, I thought that the integral $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\Phi^2\ dx\ dy$ converges. In 1D also, it seems to hold...Isn't that true?

Comment: That integral diverges in two dimensions. In polar coordinates you’re integrating over circles and it diverges logarithmically. In one dimension it still diverges but due to the contribution near the origin, at least if I haven’t gotten too mixed up.